# Processing complex JSON list to POJO

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a json response from an external API in below format.But I am not sure how to convert this to a POJO to get all these values separately later in the application

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "item_list": [
        {
            "property_value_map": {
                "Data": {
                    "content_type": "image/jpeg",
                    "data": "ZJRgABAAEASABIAAD//gAfTEVBRCBUZWNobm9sb2dpZXMgSW5jLiBWMS"
                },
                "DataType": 0,
                "LastChanged": "2015-12-11T17:21:15+00:00",
                "ObjectType": 1,
                "PersonID": 1384
            }
        }
    ],
    "page_number": 1,
    "page_size": 20,
    "total_items": 1,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "type_name": "Lnl_MultimediaObject",
    "version": "1.0"
}
```

I created a POJO as below and its converting this JSON. But the issue is I dont know how to get the value for "data" from above JSON as my item_list is Object

```
public class GetInstancesResponseVO {
    private int count;
    private List<Object> item_list;
    private int page_number;
    private int page_size;
    private int total_items;
    private int total_pages;
    private String type_name;
    private String version;

    public GetInstancesResponseVO() {}

        /***Getters Setters **/
}
```

**UPDATE**

Tried with a pojo as suggested by Jaume Morón i Tarrasa

```
public class GetInstancesResponseVO {
  private int count;
  private List<PropertyValueMap> item_list;
  private int page_number;
  private int page_size;
  private int total_items;
  private int total_pages;
  private String type_name; 
  private String version;

/***CONSTRUCTOR, SETTERS, GETTERS***/
}
```

But I am getting null . Here is my PropertyValueMap POJO;

```
public class PropertyValueMap {
  private MyData Data;
  private int DataType;
  private String LastChanged;
  private String ObjectType;
  private String PersonID;

  public PropertyValueMap() {}

  /***GETTERS,SETTERS**/
}
```

And the Data POJO;

```
public class MyData implements Serializable{
  private String content_type;
  private String data;


  public MyData() {}

  /***GETTERS, SETTERS**/
}
```

I tried Data as String in PropertValueMap POJO and in either way I am getting null as below;

```
{
"count": 1,
"item_list": [
    {
        "objectType": null,
        "data": null,
        "personID": null,
        "lastChanged": null,
        "dataType": 0
    }
],
"page_number": 1,
"page_size": 20,
"total_items": 1,
"total_pages": 1,
"type_name": "Lnl_MultimediaObject",
"property_value_map": null,
"version": "1.0"
```

}

And also the JSON response does not look like right as its missing "property_value_map". A help would be greatly appreciated as I am going to waste yet another day for it.

Comment: `item_list` should probably be a list of POJOs that represent an item, not `List<Object>`.

Comment: by item did you mean a pojo of "property_value_map" ?

Comment: You should create a new class to represent the property_value_map (ProperyValueMap p.e.) and change private List<Object> item_list; to private List<ProperyValueMap> item_list;

Comment: worth mentioning you can generate the classes out of the json, ie: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/